# Wordpress Child Post Type

Tags: wordpress, custom-post-type

Made a custom post type, "Events", great. Now I want to get a *second* custom post type and nest its menu items with the existing Events items.

1. No taxonomies allowed
2. I know there's great event plugins, this is just theoretical
3. It's gotta go INSIDE the "Events" menu, not above or below!

Should be straightforward... right? ...guise?

Comment: Try http://wordpress.stackexchange.com . SO should be for programming questions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check out http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_post_type and the bit about "show_in_menu".

You should be able to set it to something like:

```
'show_in_menu' => 'edit.php?post_type=events'
```

And it'll show up in that menu. For more control, you can always play with the $menu and $submenu global variable. Add both post_types, do a print_r on $menu and $submenu to see where everything is, and then move some things around. It'll probably look something like this:

```
add_action('admin_menu', 'change_zee_menu');
function change_zee_menu() {
    global $menu, $submenu;
    $submenu['edit.php?post_type=events'][13] = array(
            0   => 'All Sub Events',
            1   => 'edit_posts',
            2   => 'edit.php?post_type=sub_events'
    );
    $submenu['edit.php?post_type=events'][14] = array(
            0   => 'Add Sub Event',
            1   => 'edit_posts',
            2   => 'post-new.php?post_type=sub_events'
    );
}
```

Comment: Brilliant, thanks mate.. was messin around with that part earlier but didn't get it running. Works great!